# how to combine cfif and cflnclude in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, include

I have a ColdFusion program which needs to switch to another page, but which page depends on a condition.  It would be nice to write code such as

```
<cfif a GT 5>
 <cfinclude template = 'pageone.cfm'>
<cfelse>
 <cfinclude template = 'pagetwo.cfm'>
</cfif>
```

The problem is, if I include pageone or pagetwo the final `</cfif>` disappears from ColdFusion's radar, and I get an error.  Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do above?

Comment: What error do you get? The code you have given here is fine, so I suspect the problem is in an included page.

Comment: Check the code of pagetwo. May be you have an open cfif in pagetwo.cfm

Comment: like tim and keshav have said, you have an error in pageone or pagetwo. cfinclude includes the file, but then continues processing the original file, so the final cfif is included ( and anything after it ) - so isn't what is causing your error

Comment: The error was the missing </cfif> for the original <cfif>-- but I will certainly check pageone and pagetwo.  I'm glad to hear that the include works the way I thought it did, but we less experienced people can be easily confused.

Comment: @BettyMock as much as i like coldfusion, sometimes the error messages are rubbish, and on occasions just point you in a vague direction of the actual error! can you try running pageone and pagetwo individually, or do they need stuff setup in the page calling them?

Answer (score 0):

**Change your approach to something like this:**

```
<cfset a = 6>

<cfif a GT 5>
    <cfset templateTarget = 'pageone.cfm'>
<cfelse>
    <cfset templateTarget = 'pageTwo.cfm'>
</cfif>

<cfinclude template = '#templateTarget#'>
```

Comment: I did start to do things that way.  The real problem was somewhat more complex than the one I presented, and resisted that solution.